# Spring Boot possible ways to send file

Tags: file, stream, spring-boot

I found this way to send file in this tutorial
http://benashby.com/spring/serving-large-files-spring-mvc

Is there an easier way in Spring Boot to return respond with file or data from stream? I can only find tutorial how to easily send file up to server but nothing about downloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That link looks good to me, but long winded and not very separate concerns. I think `@ResponseBody Resource` would work (looking at the `ResourceHttpMessageConverter` which is registered by default). Nothing new there actually.

Comment: I wonder if I can do it easier, like returning ResponseEntity with stream or something like that. I mean there is an easy way to upload file without using HttpServletRequest (@RequestBody MultipartFile file).

Comment: @RequestParam("file")MultipartFile file  (I can't edit my previous comment.)

Comment: I was looking for something like that, especially `InputStreamResource` and `FileSystemResource` which are implementations of above Resource. Thank you very much